# How to bind values to the Animation properties?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to animate a path with storyboard in WPF.I have tried with the following code.

```
<Ellipse Name="src" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="150" Width="20" Height="30"
                        Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Red"/>
        <Path x:Name="path" StrokeDashOffset="220" StrokeDashArray="220 220" Data="M60,165 L210,210" Stroke="red" >
            <Path.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="220" To="0" Duration="{Binding duration}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.StrokeDashOffset)"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Path.Triggers>
        </Path>

        <Ellipse Name="dest" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="200" Width="20" Height="20"
                        Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Yellow"/>
```

But the values couldnt bind to the properties of `<DoubleAnimation>`.Is there any other way to bind to those properties??

Anyone pls help me to do tis.

Comment: Where is this `duration` property declared? Check for binding errors in output window.

Comment: Thats in code behind.Actually I have setted DataContext in side `<window>`.

Comment: I tried this in small sample and it worked for me. Are you sure the binding is not broken? Have you check output window for binding errors?

Comment: Dud you use DataTemplate??If not can you please give that code?

Comment: No i haven't used the `DataTemplate`. Your code + one property in DataContext of type `Duration`. Can you post code for property and how you are setting DataContext?

Comment: Setted DataContext for `<window>` as DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" and in code behind defined property as `public TimeSpan duration=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50);`

Comment: Please check my answer for the problem in your code.

Comment: Its working.But If I put all my codes that I mentioned above inside this `<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type srcview:myView}"><canvas>.....</canvas> </ControlTemplate>` binding is not working.

Comment: As per original question, it was not working in simple xaml (contentControl is mentioned nowhere) and for which i have provided solution below. Anyhow reason for not working in `ControlTemplate` might be that DataContext won't have been passed to ControlTemplate. You need to use `RealtiveSource` in binding to bind with that property. Please refrain from asking follow up questions in comments since it is not visible to larger audience here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all **`duration` should be a property** and not field if you want to bind to it.

Second, `Duration` DP of DoubleAnimation is of type `Duration` and not `TimeSpan`. So **property type should be Duration and not TimeSpan**.

Property declaration should be like this:

```
    private Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50));
    public Duration Duration
    {
        get
        {
            return duration;
        }
    }
```

Also, as per MS property name conventions, property name should be in Pascal case. So, i have updated the property name to `Duration` instead of `duration`.